# How to get max Saturday dates in a column of each month, without hardcoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max, each

How to get max Saturday dates in a column of each month in SQL Server. Can someone please help me.

Now I need only the dates which has last Saturday of month.
For example,

The table has

```
07-08-2021 - Saturday
14-08-2021 - Saturday
21-08-2021 - Saturday
28-08-2021 - Saturday

04-09-2021 - Saturday
11-09-2021 - Saturday
18-09-2021 - Saturday
25-09-2021 - Saturday
```

Suppose we are in August month, I need to select last Saturday of that month( ONLY 28-08-2021)
Suppose we are in September month, I need to select last Saturday of that month( ONLY 25-09-2021)

Output:

```
28-08-2021
25-09-2021
```

Comment: do u need count of saturday in each month?

Comment: Please check i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

A CTE is defined to populate the day name of entire month and then the requirement is filtered.

```
;with GetDates As (  
        select CAST('01-01-2021' as date) as StartDate, datename(dw, '09-01-2021') as Day_Name
        UNION ALL  
        select DATEADD(day,1, StartDate), datename(dw, DATEADD(day,1, StartDate))
        from GetDates  
        where StartDate < '09-30-2021'  
    )
    
    select max(StartDate)
    from GetDates where Day_Name = 'Saturday'
    group by month(StartDate)
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a datefield in your table (I will refer to it here as such in the below query)

```sql
with week as (
    select
      date_trunc('week', datefield + interval '2 day') - interval '2 day' as week_date
      -- ^this adjusts the week date_trunc to start on Saturday (it starts on Monday by default)
    
    from sometable  
)

select
    extract(month from week_date) as month_num,
    max(week_date) as last_saturday
    
from week
group by month_num
```

note: if you only have partial data for the current month, this query will need to be altered slightly, but you didn't give me a lot to go off of here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to calculate the Nth Weekday - which can calculate from the beginning of the month or from the end of the month.

```
  Alter Function dbo.fnGetNthWeekDay (
        @theDate datetime
      , @theWeekday int
      , @theNthDay int
        )
Returns Table
     As
 Return 

/* 
   Adapted from a version published by Peter Larrson - with minor modifications for performance
   and restructured to eliminate usage of a derived table.

   Inputs:
        @theDate        any date in the month
        @theWeekday     the weekday to calculate: 1 = Monday
                                                  2 = Tuesday
                                                  3 = Wednesday
                                                  4 = Thursday
                                                  5 = Friday
                                                  6 = Saturday
                                                  7 = Sunday
        @theNthDay      the week count where positive is from beginning of the month
                        and negative is from end of month

   Outputs:
        @theDate        the date entered
        @theNthDate     the Nth date of the month
*/

 Select theDate = @theDate
      , dt.nthDate
   From (Values (dateadd(month, datediff(month, @theNthDay, @theDate), 0)))                             As mm(FirstOfMonth)
  Cross Apply (Values (dateadd(day, 7 * @theNthDay - 7 * sign(@theNthDay + 1)
            + (@theWeekday + 6 - datediff(day, -53690, mm.FirstOfMonth) % 7) % 7, mm.FirstOfMonth)))    As dt(nthDate)
  Where @theWeekday Between 1 And 7
    And datediff(month, dt.nthDate, @theDate) = 0
    And @theNthDay In (-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Go
```

You can then call it like this:

```
Select * From dbo.fnGetNthWeekDay('2021-08-15', 6, -1) nwd
```