# How to get last satuday date of each month in sql server,Without hardcoding/dynamically...Can someone please help me

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to get last saturday's date of each month.Suppose we are in september month,Now i need last satuday date of september, which falls under 25-09-2021,Without hardcoding

Comment: Use a Calendar Table, they are an invaluable resource on *any* instance.

Comment: Make an effort - [last saturday in each month](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+last+saturday+of+each+month&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&oq=sql+server+last+saturday+of+each+month&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l4j69i64.6691j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: The same question was asked yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294032/how-to-get-max-saturday-dates-in-a-column-of-each-month-without-hardcoding/69294144#69294144

Answer (score 0):

I used  master..spt_values to generate the date. if you use some other method also you can apply the below logic to in the query to get the last Saturday.

```
 DECLARE @SessionsPerArea TABLE (idArea INT, idSession INT, startDate DATE)
 INSERT  @SessionsPerArea VALUES
 (1,1,'2021-09-01') -- add the months here
,(1,1,'2021-10-01')

 ;WITH t1 AS 
  (
    SELECT  startDate
        , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', startDate), '1900-01-01') firstInMonth
        , DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', startDate) + 1, '1900-01-01')) lastInMonth
        , COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM    @SessionsPerArea
    WHERE   idArea = 1
    GROUP BY
        startDate
 )
 , calendar AS
(
   SELECT  DISTINCT DATEADD(DAY, c.number, t1.firstInMonth) d
   FROM    t1 
   JOIN    master..spt_values c ON
        type = 'P'
   AND     DATEADD(DAY, c.number, t1.firstInMonth) BETWEEN t1.firstInMonth AND t1.lastInMonth
   )

--This part of the query returns the last saturday of the month
--logic to get the last saturday of the month
SELECT 
  A.[date]
 , A.[Weekday]
FROM 
 (
   SELECT  d as [date]
       ,Datename(WEEKDAY,d) as [Weekday]
       ,row_number() over ( partition by MONTH(d) order by d desc) as id
  FROM    calendar c
  LEFT    JOIN t1 ON t1.startDate = c.d
  WHERE Datename(WEEKDAY,d)= 'Saturday'
  ) as A
  WHERE A.id = 1
```

[image: Result]